# Uses and differences in properties?

Tags: c#-4.0

whats difference between Auto-Implemented Properties and manual properties in c#?

for Example:
Manual Properties:

```
private int uno;

    public int Uno
    {
        get { return uno; }
        set { uno = value; }
    }
```

Auto Implemented Prop:

```
public string UserLeaveCount { get; set; }
```

i found the difference and uses here  : [Auto Implemented Prop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

But Here is my Specific doubt thats "there is no instance variable in auto implemented properties and  how is it stored,returned values?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just syntactic sugar -- the compiler inserts the backing field for you.  The effect is the same, except that, of course, there's no way for you to access the backing field from your code.

From the page you linked to:

> When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.